# Problem rendering a space inside a phoenix template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I was giving a try to Phoenix Live View building a basic chat when I found a strange behaviour. Probably due to my lack of knowledge about Phoenix templates...

When trying to assign dynamically a CSS class to a component, making use of `<%= if _, do: _, else: _ =>`:

```
<div class=<%= if msg.user == @user, do: "msg local-user", else: "msg other-user" %>>
```

The problem is that this is rendered to `<div class"msg" local-user"">` instead of `<div class="msg local-user">`

Comment: Maybe you need to have double-quotes in the HTML (i.e. outside of the EEx syntax)?  Like this maybe? 
`<div class="<%= if msg.user == @user, do: "msg local-user", else: "msg other-user" %>">`

Comment: Great, I'm posting it as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have double-quotes in the HTML (i.e. *outside* of the EEx syntax), like this:

```
<div class="<%= if msg.user == @user, do: "msg local-user", else: "msg other-user" %>">
```